# Contact form position

Tags: forms

I'm trying to get the 'contact' form on my page in the middle of the webpage.

```html
<form id="contact_form" action="#" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <div class="row">
  <label for="name">Uw naam:</label><br />
  <input id="name" class="input" name="name" type="text" value="" size="30" /><br />
 </div>
 
 <div class="row">
  <label for="email">Uw e-mail:</label><br />
  <input id="email" class="input" name="email" type="text" value="" size="30" /><br />
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <label for="message">Uw vraag:</label><br />
  <textarea id="message" class="input" name="message" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea><br />
 </div>
 <input id="submit_button" type="submit" value="Verstuur bericht" />

 
</ul>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

use css:

```
#contact_form {width:400px;display:block;margin:0 auto;}
```

Answer (score -1):

## contact_form {position:absolute; top:50px;left:10px;width:500px;display:block;margin:0 auto;}